# Isomorphism in networkx with edge attributes

Tags: python, networkx, isomorphism

I'm using a Networkx function for isomorphism:

```
  GM = nx.algorithms.isomorphism.GraphMatcher(G1,G2,node_match=lambda n1,n2:n1['name']==n2['name'])
```

I want to do the same with an edge attribute called 'type' but i don't know how. 
I just tried this:

```
  GM = nx.algorithms.isomorphism.GraphMatcher(G1,G2,node_match=lambda n1,n2:n1['name']==n2['name'], edge_match= lambda G[u1][v1],G2[u2][v2]: g[u1][v1]['type'] == g2[u2][v2]['type'])
```

but it doesn't work. 
Thank you!

EDIT: 
this is from Documentation:

```
 edge_match : callable
            A function that returns True iff the edge attribute dictionary for
            the pair of nodes (u1, v1) in G1 and (u2, v2) in G2 should be
            considered equal during the isomorphism test. The function will be
            called like::

               edge_match(G1[u1][v1], G2[u2][v2])

            That is, the function will receive the edge attribute dictionaries
            of the edges under consideration. If None, then no attributes are
            considered when testing for an isomorphism.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the edge_match function as follows:

```
GM = nx.algorithms.isomorphism.GraphMatcher(G1,G2,node_match=lambda n1,n2:n1['name']==n2['name'], edge_match= lambda e1,e2: e1['type'] == e2['type'])
```

### Explanation:

Documentation says:

> **edge_match (callable)** – A function that returns True iff the edge
>   attribute dictionary for the pair of nodes (u1, v1) in G1 and (u2, v2)
>   in G2 should be considered equal during the isomorphism test. The
>   function will be called like:
>
> `edge_match(G1[u1][v1], G2[u2][v2])`

`G[u][v]` is the data dictionary for the edge (u, v).

So `lambda e1,e2: e1['type'] == e2['type']` is a function that given the **data dictionary** of 2 edges, returns true iff the type of the two edges equals.

Comment: it says KeyError 'type' . But every edges has 'type' as attribute

Comment: It works fine for me, can you run `print(G.edges(data=True))`, to see the edges?

Comment: Also what NetworkX version do you use? I have 2.2 (you can run `print(nx.__version__)` to check it)